# PYSPARK: CX_ORACLE.InterfaceError: not a query

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cx-oracle

i need to perform update query in spark job. i am trying below code. but facing issues.

```
import cx_Oracle
def query(sql):
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@s<url>/db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
v = [10]
rdd = sc.parallelize(v).coalesce(1)
rdd.foreachPartition(lambda x : [query("UPDATE db.tableSET MAPPERS ="+str(i)+" WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'") for i in x])
```

when i execute the above process i am getting below error.

```
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query
```

i tried to update manually using below code.

```
result = query("<update query>")
```

when i do this, job is executing continuously

Comment: `UPDATE` isn't a _query_, it's a _statement_.  What would you expect `cursor.fetchall()` to return after running an `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved my problem. As per Luke inputs. i used `fetchall()` which is used for querying. i need to use `commit()`. so changed the code and checked its working fine.

```
import cx_Oracle
def query(sql):
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@s<url>/db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = connection.commit()
v = [10]
rdd = sc.parallelize(v).coalesce(1)
rdd.foreachPartition(lambda x : [query("UPDATE db.tableSET MAPPERS ="+str(i)+"WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'") for i in x])
```