# Getting cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query exception while trying to run alter system command

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am getting `cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query` error while trying to end all user sessions for a specified user.

```
import cx_Oracle

try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@someip/ora12c')
    cursor = con.cursor()

    result= cursor.execute("select USERNAME,SID,SERIAL#,COMMAND,STATUS from v$session where USERNAME='uname'")


    for session in result:
        query_string="ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '@1,@2' IMMEDIATE".replace("@1",str(session[1])).replace("@2",str(session[2]))
        print(query_string)
        cursor.execute(query_string)
        con.commit()

except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Unable to kill user sessions, Subsequent steps may FAIL!!')
    print(e)

finally:
    if cursor: cursor.close()
    if con: con.close()
```

Running the above code I am getting:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '1526,30533' IMMEDIATE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oracleKillSession.py", line 10, in <module>
    for session in result:
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query
```

I tried the solutions at [PYSPARK: CX_ORACLE.InterfaceError: not a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285101/pyspark-cx-oracle-interfaceerror-not-a-query) but that didn't help resolving the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate over a cursor (`for session in result`) and then use the same cursor to execute a statement. You'll need a separate cursor for that, or you'll need to fetch all of the rows from the cursor first. So one of these two approaches will work for you:

Option 1:

```
alter_cursor = con.cursor()
for session in result:
    alter_cursor.execute(query_string)
```

Option 2:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
for session in result:
    cursor.execute(query_string)
```